# JTable Sorting - Selecting a row

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have a JTable where I used an integer comparator along with a `TableRowSorter`
`trs.setComparator(columnIndex, new IntComparator())` and `table.setRowSorter(trs)` to sort.

The sorting works as intended however I have a mouse clicked event which uses `int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint())` and `DefaultTabelModel mod = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()` to get the values of the row selected with `mod.getValueAt(row, 0)`.

This gets the value of the row at this position in the original sorting of the JTable, not the row that is there now after sorting. How can I make this work for the sorted table as well?

Thanks

EDIT: Example code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test extends JFrame{
    JTable table = new JTable();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public Test() {
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setupTable();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
    public void setupTable() {

        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
                {1, 15, 17},
                {2, 45, 7},
                {3, 9, 26},
                {4, 65, 65}
        };
        Object[] columns = new Object[]{"ID", "X", "Y"};

        table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(720, 400));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> trs = new TableRowSorter(table.getModel());


        class IntComparator implements Comparator {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Integer int1 = (Integer) o1;
                Integer int2 = (Integer) o2;
                return int1.compareTo(int2);
            }

            public boolean equals(Object o2) {
                return this.equals(o2);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            trs.setComparator(i, new IntComparator());
        }
        table.setRowSorter(trs);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (0 <= row && row <= table.getRowCount()) {
                    DefaultTableModel mod = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                    String ID = String.valueOf(mod.getValueAt(trs.convertRowIndexToView(row), 0));
                    System.out.println(ID);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the functions:
[JTable#convertRowIndexToModel(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int))
and
[JTable#convertRowIndexToView(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView(int))

You will want to convert your row that you get from `rowAtPoint` to the row that is displayed using `JTable#convertRowIndexToView(int)`

Comment: mod.getValueAt(trs.convertRowIndexToView(row), 0)); I used this to get the row and it was correct the first time, however if I sorted again, either by a different column or reversed the sorting, it wouldn't get the correct row. Do you know why this would be? I haven't used the convertRowIndexToModel function.

Comment: What row does it get the second time? Without a better code snippet, I can only really guess.

Comment: Playing around with it a bit more it seems really weird. It sorts the rows correctly when sorting lowest->highest int values, but incorrectly on highest->low values. e.g. sorting by one column by lowest y value gives IDs:3, 2, 1, 4. When I reverse the sorting it reads correctly but selects ID:2, 3, 4, 1 instead of 4, 1, 2, 3. I'll probably have to get a proper code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Yea it sounds like your comparator is off and not implemented correctly. Check your logic for that to be sure you did it right.

Comment: The comparator sorts it correctly. I can see the correct sortings, just when sorting in reverse order It doesn't select them correctly. The Table view is still correct

Answer (score 1):

Using `mod.getValueAt(trs.convertRowIndexToModel(row), 0)` instead of `mod.getValueAt(trs.convertRowIndexToView(row), 0)` selected sorted rows correctly.

Thanks searchengine27